# How to capture large numbers correctly from user voice input

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

What is the best practice to capture large numbers from user voice input in dialogFlow? in my app user has to give 6 digit numbers as input. If user has to provide a value of lets say 189725 from google mini then it's not working. Google Mini is not able to capture correct number. Voice input was "one hundred eighty nine thousand seven hundred twenty five", google mini captured "189 thousand 725", I need 189725. For smaller numbers like 500 it's working fine. how do I capture large numbers correctly?

[First screenshot of intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAPzx.png)

[Second screenshot of intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQvNt.png)

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the Intent you're trying to use to capture this?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the intent.

Comment: If I say each numbers like "one eight nine seven two five" then it's capturing it as "1897 to 5" and not working.

Comment: Any one with any suggestions? I am not able to make this work.